# How do i change color on id inside list more efficiently?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<ul>` on my website, inside the `<ul>` is a total of four `<li>`.
I have all of them seperatly in a class called `.list`. I need them to have different colors so i made four different `<id>` for all of them. `<id="list1">`, `<id="list2">`, `<id="list3">`, `<id="list4">`.

```css
.list{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.list h3{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 z-index: 4;
 height: 80px;
}


#list4:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(151, 215, 196);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

#list3:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(215, 194, 151);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

#list2:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(189, 215, 151);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

#list1:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list" id="list1">
     <a href="#content1" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>contact</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list" id="list2">
     <a href="#content2" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>events</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list" id="list3">
     <a href="#content3" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>band</h3>
     </a>
    <li class="list" id="list4">
     <a href="#main" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>home</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
   </ul>
```

As you can see, this is not very efficient. And i can't seem to find a better way of achieving the same result. Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using an 'id' instead of a new div

Comment: @ketan i'm sorry, i meant id. Edited the question.

Comment: @Demerkies I'm sorry, i meant id.

Comment: Efficiency is about **not repeating yourself**. Anything that is used repeatable should be placed in a class and applied to all the relevant elements. Anything that is **not** repeated can be attached to an ID **or** a specific second class.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - **[CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D I can not see how this helps my scenario at all. I suggest you read the question again.

Comment: You're asking about improving code. That's an subject for CodeReview...but that's just my opinion. Are ID's efficient? - Yes. Is repeating code? No.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for clarifying this, now i know the next time something like this comes up.

Comment: @Paulie_D Borderline case... after all, we have concrete code and possible concrete answers. Although the latter might be heavily opinion biased.

Comment: @JánosWeisz The issue here, **it seems to me**, is that the answers aren't necessarily more efficient that the original. Strip away the repeated code (which is, by it's nature inefficient) and you are still left with single selectors for each individual item. Whether we use an ID or a specific selector not really relevant as, codewise, one is "efficient" as the other..although an ID would be **faster** and have higher **specificity**

Answer (score 0):

As the only thing that is different between the `li` elements is the colour when hovering. I suggest put all the styling on the class `list` and use `nth-child()` like so:

```
.list:nth-child(1):hover{
    background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
}

...
```

This way the unique Ids list1, list2 etc becomes unnecessary

```css
.list{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.list h3{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 z-index: 4;
 height: 80px;
}

.list:nth-child(1):hover{
  background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
}

.list:nth-child(2):hover{
  background-color: rgb(189, 215, 151);
}

.list:nth-child(3):hover{
  background-color: rgb(215, 194, 151);
}

.list:nth-child(4):hover{
  background-color: rgb(151, 215, 196);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content1" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>contact</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content2" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>events</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content3" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>band</h3>
     </a>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#main" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>home</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: heh noticed that, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.list h3{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 z-index: 4;
 height: 80px;
}


.list:nth-of-type(4):hover{
 
        background-color: rgb(151, 215, 196);

}

.list:nth-of-type(3):hover{
 
 background-color: rgb(215, 194, 151);
 
  
}

.list:nth-of-type(2):hover{
 
 background-color: rgb(189, 215, 151);
 
}

.list:nth-of-type(1):hover{
 
 background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
 

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content1" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>contact</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content2" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>events</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#content3" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>band</h3>
     </a>
    <li class="list">
     <a href="#main" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>home</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
   </ul>
```

> Except your `backgroundcolor` nothing seems to differ in your other `.list` so i removes the replica properties from other `.list`

`.list:nth-of-type()` can be used instead of the id's

Answer (score 0):

You can strip duplicate declaration of CSS properties. For example, `float: right` is defined in both `.list` and `#list3`.

Since - in your case - the given element matches both CSS selectors, the definitions in `.list` will be first applied to your elements (since class based match has [lower priority](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector) than id based match), and *then* the definitions in `#list3` will be applied, (in your situation, needlessly) overriding the conflicting values.

**HTML**

```
<!-- this element will be styled first by .list, then by #list3 -->
<li class="list" id="list3">
```

That is, an (IMO) efficient way to *significantly* reduce both the size of your CSS and the computing power it takes to apply your definitions to the corresponding elements would be **defining the common properties** in a class selector, and then defining those properties that are individual per element, or per selector:

**CSS**

```
/* applied to all elements with class list */
.list {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* applied to element with ID list3 when it is under mouse */
#list3:hover {
    background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
}
```

Of course, you can also define a common (class selector based) property-set for `.list:hover` and override that with ID selectors, if you need different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As per efficiency concern id is efficient But, i suggest css apply using class.  You can add another class as per color. And when you want apply specific color then add that class in HTMl element.

```css
.list{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.list h3{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 z-index: 4;
 height: 80px;
}


.color4:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(151, 215, 196);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

.color3:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(215, 194, 151);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

.color2:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(189, 215, 151);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}

.color1:hover{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(151, 190, 215);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list color1" id="menu_list">
     <a href="#content1" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>contact</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list color2" id="menu_list">
     <a href="#content2" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>events</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="list color3" id="menu_list">
     <a href="#content3" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>band</h3>
     </a>
    <li class="list color4" id="menu_list">
     <a href="#main" class="smoothScroll">
      <h3>home</h3>
     </a> 
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, you are trying some good work, but when you have added class for all your list items, no need to re-write the whole code again and again for different ids. You must follow "**DRY**" principal, ie, ***Do-Not-Repeat***. Follow the following CSS Code:

```
.list{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(189, 215, 151);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 line-height: 55px;
 margin-top: -16px;
}
#list1:hover{background:red;}
#list2:hover{background:orange;}
#list3:hover{backgorund:green;}
#list4:hover{background:pink;}
```